# Sending HashMap to SQL DB

Tags: java, mysql, hashmap

My code is wrong somehow :/

```
    public static Connection con = null;
    public static void createConnection()
   {
     try
     {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       String str1 = "s1.infinitysrv.com:3306";
       String str2 = "sagesca1_hiscores";
       String str3 = "sagesca1_server";
       String str4 = "pass";
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + str1 + "/" + str2, str3, str4);
       stmt = con.createStatement();
       System.out.println("Connection to SQL database successful!");
     } catch (Exception localException) {
       System.out.println("Connection to SQL database failed");
       localException.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
       public static Map<String, Clan> clans;
   public static boolean sendClans(){
    try {       
        try {
            clans = (HashMap<String, Clan>) XStreamUtil.getXStream().fromXML(new FileInputStream("data/clans.xml"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            clans = new HashMap<String, Clan>();
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, Clan> entries : clans.entrySet()) {
            final Clan clan = entries.getValue();
            clan.setTransient();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO clans(name,roomOwner) values (?, ?)");
            ps.setString(1, clan.getName());
            ps.setString(2, clan.getOwner());
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
```

Here's my ClanManager that calls the method sendClan

```
    private Map<String, Clan> clans;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ClanManager() {
    Logger.getInstance().info("Loading clans....");
    try {
        clans = (HashMap<String, Clan>) XStreamUtil.getXStream().fromXML(new FileInputStream("data/clans.xml"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        clans = new HashMap<String, Clan>();
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, Clan> entries : clans.entrySet()) {
        final Clan clan = entries.getValue();
        clan.setTransient();
        //Hiscores.sendClans();
    }
    Logger.getInstance().info("Loaded " +clans.size()+ " SageScape clans.");
}
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is but the error points to this when I run my server:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO clans(name,roomOwner) values (?, ?)");
```

I don't know what's wrong with the code, if anyone could help me I would love you forever.

Comment: What is the mapping between the two columns that you've created and the `Map` that you have? (i.e. what does `owner` and `name` map to with respect to the `clans` `Map` that you have)

Comment: owner is the roomOwner and name is the roomName how would I make the table on the mysql db also, because I think it might be different somehow.

Comment: And so your `Clan` class is populated with this info? And you've appropriate `getter/setter` methods to access these values?

Comment: Also, can you post the code for your `Clan` class?

Comment: This is my Clan class I believe it sets those values. http://pastebin.com/TBKw2kN4

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you've created a table in your DB that has a `schema` which is somewhat like this (this is a bit MySQL specific):

```
CREATE TABLE ClanTable(
    name        varchar(30),
    roomOwner   varchar(30)
)
```

Now for you to insert data into this table using JDBC, I would recommend creating a method for inserting data in your `database` using a `PreparedStatement`. If you're new to JDBC, obviously you would want to read through ["JDBC Basics"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) to understand how to use JDBC in the first place.

Assuming a table structure as above, the `PreparedStatement` for this would be something like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ClanTable(name,roomOwner) values (?, ?)");
```

You would then iterate through your `map` and execute this statement. Note that if your map has a less number of entries, it would be okay to execute something like this:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Clan> entries: clans.entrySet()){
    Clan clan = entries.getValue();
    ps.setString(1, clan.getName());
    ps.setString(1, clan.getOwner());

    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Would I keep the values as ?,?

Comment: @BrandonTylerJones A little bit of reading on [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) might help you understand the significance of '?' over here

Comment: NVm - forgot to put it in a try and catch.

Comment: There is something wrong with my code my server wouldn't start back up with this: http://pastebin.com/8bKEfx3W

Comment: Bleh, I hate seeing someone go to the effort of a good answer and then have it not accepted.

Comment: The for loop is not reliable because the disk writes may not be quick enough to keep up with the for loop. Thats why passing the HashMap is more useful.